# iPhone SE3 makes weird noise

Tags: iphone, audio

I bought an iPhone SE3 phone for my son a few months ago. Recently, it started producing weird sounds:

- When pressing the Home button it makes a loud click
- When playing any audio it produces high pitch noise

Restarting the phone solves the problem temporarily but it comes back in a few days or weeks. I took it to the reseller and they told me to do a factory reset on the phone and use a brand new iCloud account to log in, but this seems more like a hardware problem.

Did anyone see similar? What can cause this problem?

Comment: iCloud surely has nothing to do with it. If a factory reset does not solve the issue it is most likely hardware. Also, since this only appears after some time it could be related to heat or some effect that takes time to build up. Can you get a replacement?

Comment: I was suspecting hardware reset too. I think I still have 6 months from the guarantee period. I will return the phone to the store and will try to ask for replacement